# writing multiple data calculated from a function in the same file

Tags: python

I am trying to write a data calculated from this function in a file. But the function is called number of times. Say there are 9 numbers in another file and this function will calculate the root for each of those 9 numbers. These 9 roots from this function should be written in the same file. But the way I have done it here will write calculated root in the file but the next one will replace this in the file. There are other mathematical functions that are carried out for each of those 9 numbers before this function is called  therefore the functions are called again and again separately.Is it possible to write them all in the same file? Thank you.

```
def Newton(poly, start):
    """ Newton's method for finding the roots of a polynomial."""
    x = start 
    poly_diff = poly_differentiate(poly)
    n = 1
    counter = 0
    r_i = 0

    cFile = open("curve.dat", "w")   
    while True:
        if (n >= 0) and (n < 1):
            break

        x_n = x - (float(poly_substitute(poly, x)) / poly_substitute(poly_diff, x))

        if x_n == x:
            break

        x = x_n # this is the u value corresponding to the given time

        n -= 1
        counter += 1
        x = str(x)
        cFile.write('\n' + x + '\n')

    if r_i:
        print "t(u) = ", (x, counter)

    else:
        print "t(u) = ", x


    cFile.close
```

After following the suggestions I got I changed the code to the following:

```
def Newton(poly, start):
    """ Newton's method for finding the roots of a polynomial."""
    x = start 
    poly_diff = poly_differentiate(poly)
    n = 1
    counter = 0

    while True:
        if (n >= 0) and (n < 1):
            break

        x_n = x - (float(poly_substitute(poly, x)) / poly_substitute(poly_diff, x))

        if x_n == x:
            break

        x = x_n # this is the u value corresponding to the given time

        n -= 1
        counter += 1
        yield x 

    Bezier(x)

def Bezier(u_value) :
    """ Calculating sampling points using rational bezier curve equation"""
    u = u_value

    p_u = math.pow(1 - u, 3) * 0.7 + 3 * u * math.pow(1 - u, 2) * 0.23 \
        + 3 * (1 - u) * math.pow(u, 2) * 0.1 + math.pow(u, 3) * 0.52

    p_u = p_u * w

    d = math.pow(1 - u, 3) * w + 3 * u * w * math.pow(1 - u, 2) + 3 * (1 - u) *\ 
        w * math.pow(u, 2) + math.pow(u, 3) * w

    p_u = p_u / d

    yield p_u

    plist = list (p_u)
    print plist
```

I followed the same thing in the Bezier() function but plist is not created as it doesn't print anything. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function does **two things**: It calculates the roots of a polynomial, and it writes the result to an output file. Functions should ideally do **one thing**.

So, try breaking this up into a function that receives a polynomial and returns a list containing the roots, and then just write that list to a file in one step.

The simplest way to modify your function would be to replace the lines

```
x = str(x)
cFile.write('\n' + x + '\n')
```

with

```
yield x
```

Then you can call your function like this:

```
roots = list(Newton(polynomial, start))
```

To understand this, read about [generators](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators). To write the resulting list to a file, you can use this code:

```
with open("curve.dat", "w") as output_file:
    output_file.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in roots)
```

Comment: I did with the list before. Like with the files even in the list the next one replaces the current values. How do I append the values when the function is called again? Thanks

Comment: or `for root in Newton(...): output_file.writeline(root)`.

Comment: @Bjorn I created another function to write the roots in a file and copied the above code but it displays a syntax error pointing to the first line of code that comes after this function. I can't understand what am I doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You need to show the code and the error. This should probably be a separate question.

Comment: @Bjorn I have solved the syntax error. That was just a silly mistake sorry. I have changed my question above. Could you kindly go through it. Thank you.

Comment: You have to create the list outside of the function: `list(Bezier(value))`. Please read the tutorial about generators I have linked in my answer.

Comment: If I have to post the code again then would that be a new question or should I edit my question? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not completely understanding what you are asking I think the answer can be boiled down to:

Open the file in append mode, not in write mode. So instead of

```
cFile = open("curve.dat", "w")
```

do

```
cFile = open("curve.dat", "a")
```

Comment: Thanks will try it and see what happens.

Comment: This works but the problem is every time I run the code the values will keep adding in the file which is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

why use yield in Bezier, it doesn't return multiple values, so you can change:

```
yield p_u
plist = list (p_u)
print plist
```

to:

```
print list(p_u)
return p_u
```